# Using DateTime to get the GetLastWriteTime of a file, from any cultural format, and then converting it to yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: c#, date, datetime

We have an application that is used on our users PCs in the US, UK and Japan and could possibly be in other countries in EMEA or APAC.

The application requires our users to use a folderBrowserDialog to browse to a folder where specific files are stored.  The application will then take the path of each file and along with the last update date of a file and passes the path and date of each file as parameters to an executable that then processes the files in a separate thread.

I use the following code to get the date and time:

```
DateTime fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(folder containing all my files);
```

In the US the fileDate is always in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format, I use string manipulation to get fileDate into yyyy/MM/dd format as I need it.

The problem is that when our users in the UK, Japan, Germany or other countries use the app the fileDate is not in MM/dd/yyyy format, it could be dd/MM/yyyy or yyyy/dd/MM and then everything gets thrown off.

Is there a way get fileDate to always be in a standard format such as yyyy/MM/dd so I never have to worry about the local time format nor having to use string manipulation to get it in the format that I need.

I have tried

```
fileDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

but this does not seem to work as no date is getting passed to our executable.

I have searched Stack Overflow and Internet but I cannot find a solution that works.

Below is the code I use to convert the date into a string and format it the way I like

```
                    DateTime fileDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(collectionLog);
                    orgDate = Convert.ToString(fileDate);


                    stringMod1 = orgDate.Replace(" ", "#");
                    stringMod2 = orgDate.Substring(0, stringMod1.IndexOf("#"));
                    stringMod3 = stringMod2.Split('/');
                    stopDate.Text = stringMod3[2] + "/" + stringMod3[0] + "/" + stringMod3[1];

                    DateTime fiveDaysEarlier = fileDate.AddDays(-5);

                    beginDate = Convert.ToString(fiveDaysEarlier);
                    stringMod1 = beginDate.Replace(" ", "#");
                    stringMod2 = beginDate.Substring(0, stringMod1.IndexOf("#"));
                    stringMod4 = stringMod2.Split('/');
                    startDate.Text = stringMod4[2] + "/" + stringMod4[0] + "/" + stringMod4[1];
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `DateTime` is just a number representing Date and Time, Display format is only for *displaying* / Presentation.

Comment: Show how you are passing the information to the .exe.

Comment: `and passes the path and date of each file as parameters to an executable` . How are you passing the Dates ? are you converting them to string and them passing it ?

Comment: yes, before I pass the path and date I first convert them to string, which I then pass to the executable.

Comment: @dshafie72, What is the code that you use for passing Date to EXE ?

Comment: Would you like the entire code I use to pass the parameters to executable or are you wanting to know if I first convert them to a string before I pass them.  I convert both the path and date to strings before I pass them and everything works.  After my string manipulation I pass the date in the following format yyyy/MM/dd but my manipulation is based on a MM/dd/yyyy format.  When the local format changes to say UK standard dd/MM/yyyy the string manipulation nolonger outputs right.  Thus was looking for a way to standardize any format to yyyy/MM/dd so I do not have to use string manipulation.

Comment: @dshafie72, instead of rolling out your own solution use customized format with `DateTime.ToString`. I have posted an answer take a look at it.

Comment: `I have tried fileDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`  That should work.  Something else is amiss.  Maybe you don't want the time...just the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better if you could pass `DateTime` object to your EXE, but it seems you want to pass Dates as string to your exe and that too in particular format of `yyyy/MM/dd`. Use:

```
stopDate.Text = fileDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will always give you a date string in same format irrespective of culture. Use the same for other date:

```
startDate.Text = fiveDaysEarlier.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks like it did the trick.  No string manipulation needed.  That was so easy, thanks a million.